# Display dash datatable through callback

Tags: reactjs, datatable, callback, plotly, plotly-dash

I want to be able to return a populated dash table based on the results from an input search. I've tried 2 methods so far - returning the entire DashTable in the callback output and returning the columns and data separately in the callback.  Both options haven't been working for me.  I've included the relevant code for each option and the error message that results from each:

1. Return the data and columns separately:

```
        @app.callback(
        [Output('table', 'data'),
        Output('table', 'columns')],
        [Input("button", "n_clicks")], state=[State('url', 'value')])
    def update_table(n_click:int, url):
        if n_click>1:
            summary, table = summarizer(url)
            columns=[{"name": i, "id": i, "deletable": True, "selectable": True} for i in table.columns]
            table = table.to_dict('records')
            return table, columns
        else: 
            return [], []
```

The app.layout contains the following line

```
     html.Div(dt.DataTable(id='table'))
```

The error message that results from this is:

Objects are not valid as a React child

[image: 1]

The second approach was to pass in the entire DataTable through the callback and display it using just the html.Div in the layout like this

```
@app.callback(
    Output('table', 'children'),
    [Input("button", "n_clicks")], state=[State('url', 'value')])
def update_table(n_click:int, url):
    if n_click>1:
        summary, table = summarizer(url)
        columns=[{"name": i, "id": i, "deletable": True, "selectable": True} for i in table.columns]
        table = table.to_dict('records')
        return dt.DataTable(data=table, columns=columns)
    else: 
        return []
```

```
html.Div(id='table')
```

The corresponding error was

```
[Objects are not valid as a React child][2]
```

This error is confusing to me since it seems to be regarding the column definition however I can't pass in an array and the documentation asks for a dictionary.

Full code sample:

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
import dash_table as dt
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State
import sd_material_ui
from newspaper import Article
import gensim
from gensim.summarization import summarize
from dash.exceptions import PreventUpdate
from newspaper import fulltext
import requests
import pandas as pd
import yake
import nltk
from newsapi import NewsApiClient


leftSources = ["cnn", "buzzfeed", "the-washington-post", "bbc-news", "vice-news", "newsweek", "techcrunch", "reuters", "politico", "newsweek", "msnbc"]
rightSources = ["fox-news", "national-review", "new-york-magazine", "breitbart-news", "business-insider", "the-wall-street-journal", "bloomberg", "the-washington-times", "the-hill", "the-american-conservative"]

# importing CSS
external_stylesheets = ['https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css']

# similarArticleURL
getSimilarArticlesURL = "https://us-central1-secure-site-266302.cloudfunctions.net/getSimilarArticles?keywords="
getKeywordsURL = "https://us-central1-secure-site-266302.cloudfunctions.net/getKeyword?text="
getArticleTextURL = "https://us-central1-secure-site-266302.cloudfunctions.net/getArticleText?url="

allData = pd.DataFrame()


# instantiating dash application
app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.BOOTSTRAP])
server = app.server # the flask app

# helper functions
def generate_table(dataframe, max_rows=10):
    return html.Table([
        html.Thead(
            html.Tr([html.Th(col) for col in dataframe.columns])
        ),
        html.Tbody([
            html.Tr([
                html.Td(dataframe.iloc[i][col]) for col in dataframe.columns
            ]) for i in range(min(len(dataframe), max_rows))
        ])
    ])

app.layout = html.Div([

    html.Div(html.H3("Brief.Me"), style={'font-weight':'bold','background-color':'darkorange', 'color':'white','text-align':'center'}),

    html.Br(),
    html.Br(),

    dbc.Row([

        dbc.Col(dbc.Input(id='url', type='url', size=30, placeholder="Type or copy/paste an URL"), width={'size':6, 'order':1, 'offset':3}),
        dbc.Col(dbc.Button("Summarize", id='button', n_clicks=1, color="primary", className="mr-1"), width={'order':2})

        ]),

    html.Br(),

    # dbc.Row([

    #     dbc.Col(dcc.Loading(html.Div(html.Div(id="summary"), style={'font-weight':'bold'})), width={'size':6, 'offset':3})

    # ]),

    html.Div(id='table')

    ],
)

def fetch_similar_articles(keyword):

    tokenizer = nltk.data.load('tokenizers/punkt/english.pickle')

    newsapi = NewsApiClient(api_key='ce7482cbd40f4d90a8eea404e7702db6')

    top_headlines = newsapi.get_top_headlines(q=keyword,
                                              sources='bbc-news,the-wall-street-journal,the-washington-post,fox-news,bloomberg, vice-news, politico, reuters, the-hill',
                                              language='en')

    return top_headlines["articles"]

def fetch_article_text(url):
  try:
    article = Article(url)
    article.download()
    article.parse()
    return article.text
  except:
    return None

def summarizer(url):
    global allData

    leftSummaries, rightSummaries = {}, {}
    text = fetch_article_text(url)
    main_summary = summarize(text)

    keywords = extract_keywords(text)
    urls = []

    rightData, leftData, allData = get_articles_content(keywords)
    rightDf, leftDf = pd.DataFrame(rightData), pd.DataFrame(leftData)
    allSources = pd.concat([rightDf, leftDf], axis=1)

    return main_summary, allData

def get_articles_content(keywords):
    '''
    This function will return a row of the dataframe where there is a title, source, url and summary. 
    '''
    allResults, leftRows, rightRows = [], [], []

    for keyword in keywords:

        articleList = fetch_similar_articles(keyword)

        for elem in articleList:
            source = elem['source']
            url = elem['url']
            title = elem['title']
            text = fetch_article_text(url)

            if text is not None and len(text) > 1:
                summary = summarize(text)

                allResults.append({'title': title, 'url': url,'source': source, 'summary': summary})
                if source in leftSources:
                    leftRows.append(pd.DataFrame({'title': title, 'url': url,'source': source, 'summary': summary}))
                elif source in rightSources:
                    rightRows.append(pd.DataFrame({'title': title, 'url': url, 'source': source, 'summary': summary}))

    allResults = pd.DataFrame(allResults)
    return leftRows, rightRows, allResults

def extract_keywords_yake(text, phrase_length, num_keywords):

  custom_kw_extractor = yake.KeywordExtractor(n=phrase_length, top=num_keywords)
  keywords = custom_kw_extractor.extract_keywords(text)

  return keywords

def extract_keywords(text):
    '''
    Returns a list of keywords given the article text. 
    '''
    global getKeywordsURL

    getKeywordsURL += text
    keywordRes = extract_keywords_yake(text, 2, 5)
    keywords = []

    for pair in keywordRes:
        keywords.append(pair[1])

    return keywords


@app.callback( # Output('summary', 'children')
    Output('table', 'children'),
    [Input("button", "n_clicks")], state=[State('url', 'value')])
def update_table(n_click:int, url):
    if n_click>1:
        summary, table = summarizer(url)
        columns=[{"name": i, "id": i, "deletable": True, "selectable": True} for i in table.columns]
        table = table.to_dict('records')
        return dt.DataTable(data=table, columns=columns)
    else: 
        return [], []

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0', port=8080)
```

Comment: Could you post a reproducible example of your code?

Comment: @KristianHaga added a reproducible example of the code - thanks!